# MYSQL Count Rows Where Max

Tags: mysql

This is my table of results:

```
+------------+--------+--------+
| tournament | player | Points |
+------------+--------+--------+
| 1          | Bob    | 9      |
| 1          | Jeff   | 2      |
| 1          | Steve  | 1      |
| 2          | Bob    | 5      |
| 2          | Jeff   | 3      |
| 2          | Steve  | 8      |
| 2          | Paul   | 4      |
| 3          | Bob    | 9      |
| 3          | Jeff   | 3      |
| 3          | Steve  | 2      |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

I want to find out how many times a player has won a tournament. Therefore I should get these results back:

```
Bob: 2
Steve: 1
Jeff: 0
Paul: 0
```

How would I do this?

Comment: first query the won tournaments and then query the count grouped by the player.

Comment: No, it's not that easy. So I think there's also not really a reason to vote to close!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go (read the comments from inside to outside):

```
select /*3. and finally we left join the original table to get all names and display the number of wins again*/
outerq.player,
coalesce(subq.wins, 0) as wins
from
Table1 outerq
left join (
  select /*2. Now we determine how much tournaments each player won*/
  ot.player,
  count(*) as wins
  from (
    select /*1. First we determine the winners per tournament here*/
    *
    from
    Table1 t
    where Points = (select max(Points) from Table1 st where st.tournament = t.tournament)
) ot
group by ot.player
) subq on outerq.player = subq.player
group by outerq.player
order by wins desc
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/495376/6/0)